# Calling and executing python script from another directory

Tags: python

I am trying to accomplish the following:
Directory Structure:

Python --> scripts --> common (This is where I am putting some common scripts)
Python --> scripts --> lab (This is where I have the main scripts that are trying to import from the common folder. Then I'm trying to get the output from the script I am calling here)

I have tried sys.append and sys.insert but so far no luck.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/user01/Documents/Python/scripts/common')
import auth_script
```

I need to get the output from the script and then using f-string method insert it in the script under the (lab directory).

Thank you.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I get this error. 
No module named 'auth_script'

Comment: And you do have a file called `auth_script.py` in `/Users/user01/Documents/Python/scripts/common`?

Comment: Yes, I do have the file in there.

Comment: [does this code help?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-from-sibling-directory/)?

Comment: I think there is an issue with the sys.path. When I do an import I see the folders from a directory above but I can't see any folders in the same directory as scripts.

Comment: Ok not ideal but since I don't know what the issue is here. I moved the "common" folder under "Python" instead of "scripts" and was able to import it. So basically "sys.path.append" isn't working for me.